# Debug NSString variables with Apple Script Actions in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, applescript, lldb

While debugging an iOS app I am trying to get a screenshot via Breakpoint with the following Apple Script:

[image]

> set screencapture to "/usr/sbin/screencapture -l 1586
>   ~/Downloads/screenshots/photo-@(char*) [myStringVar UTF8String]@.png"
>   -- do shell script screencapture

but it fails because the @exp@ output quotes (") from **myStringVar** and messes up with the **set** assignment so I get this error from lldb

> AppleScript '-viewDidAppear:' breakpoint action failed : A identifier
>   can’t go after this “"”.

How can I overcome this and make sure the @exp@ output doesn't have quotes ? Replace the string in my Apple Script ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the expression construct the whole filename, like

```
(NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat: @"~/Downloads/screenshots/photo-%@.png", [self.entryId UTF8String]]
```

That way you wouldn't get any quotes inserted.  You could probably do the whole AppleScript this way if you need to.

BTW, the cast is required because we don't have debug information for NSString stringWithFormat...